# OnSelectionChange trigger works only after page reload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a simple script that is triggered when the selected cell is changed. Unfortunately, when the document is freshly opened, the script does not start, no matter how many cells I click on. It starts working only after reloading the document page.
I'm not a programmer, I write small scripts just for my own convenience and I don't have deep knowledge in this field. Originally I wanted to add in the code an reload page onOpen. But I don't know how to do it, and probably there are smarter solutions. So please help.
I attach the code. If the problem is there...

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
 
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
const cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
const item = cell.getValue().split("\n")[0];
const iteml = item.length;
const state = cell.getValue().split("\n")[1];
var rich = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
var style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle();

switch (state) {
      case "OK":
        cell.setValue(item + "\n" + "low");
        var val = cell.getValue().toString();
        rich.setText(val);
        style.setForegroundColor("Orange");
        style.setFontSize(8); 
        rich.setTextStyle(iteml,iteml+4,style.build()); 
        var format = rich.build()
        cell.setRichTextValue(format); 
      break;

      case "low":
        cell.setValue(item + "\n" + "empty");
        var val = cell.getValue().toString();
        rich.setText(val);
        style.setForegroundColor("Red");
        style.setFontSize(8); 
        rich.setTextStyle(iteml,iteml+6,style.build()); 
        var format = rich.build()
        cell.setRichTextValue(format); 
      break;

      case "empty":
        cell.setValue(item + "\n" + "OK");
        var val = cell.getValue().toString();
        rich.setText(val);
        style.setForegroundColor("Green");
        style.setFontSize(8); 
        rich.setTextStyle(iteml,iteml+3,style.build()); 
        var format = rich.build()
        cell.setRichTextValue(format); 
      break;
      }

sheet.setActiveSelection("A1:A1");
}
```

Comment: I have had the same experience.  Once the `onSelectionChange()` trigger is created in the script editor you have to exit and reload the file for it to become active.  This also happens for me with `onChange()` installed trigger.